# What events do http.IncomingMessage implement nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been looking into nodejs and was wondering how to get POST requests. I had a look online and found that if I used the 'data' event on the request I could get the post requests. I don't know whether the documentation has changed but on the events section of the api it only has the 'close' event.

Does the 'data' event still work and if so why isn't in the documentation?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the 'data' event still work and if so why isn't in the documentation?

Yeah, it'll work. And, it is documented, but it's inherited behavior.

> It implements the [Readable Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) interface, as well as the following additional events, methods, and properties.

Events are documented with the class which implements them, so `'close'` is documented with `http.IncomingMessage` while `'data'`, `'end'`, etc. are documented under `stream.Readable`.

Comment: oh ok, I thought I wasn't looking properly! Thankyou